# Creating form for associated has_many model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a 'Business' model which has_many 'Hours'. Each Hour record has a start_time and an end_time, 
and there's an Hour record for each day of the week for a given business.

I have a form where I only update the hours for a business -- nothing else about the business. In that case it makes sense to have the Hours controller do the updating. But I can't figure out exactly how to set the form up correctly.

Here's what I have so far, but with each hour sent as a param, I need to know if it's the start_time or end_time and which day it's associated with. In the select_tag, hour.day contains an integer 0-6 which represents a day of the week (Sunday through Saturday).

```
=form_tag({:controller => 'hours', :action => "update_multiple"}, :remote => :true) do |f|

  -business.hours.each do |hour|
    =fields_for hour do |hour_fields|
      =select_tag 'hour[days_nums][#{hour.day}]', options_for_select(possible_hours, :start_time)

class Business < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :hours, :as => :hourable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :hours

end

class Hour < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :hourable, :polymorphic => true

end


create_table "hours", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "hourable_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "hourable_type"
  t.integer  "day"
  t.time     "start_time"
  t.time     "stop_time"
end
```

How can I set this up?
Thanks!

Comment: OK, let me know if you need more than what I just added. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fl00r, you definitely got me to this solution, you made me realize that I should use the form_for @business, however I just needed to change the controller and action:

```
-form_for @business, :url => {:controller => 'hours', :action => "update_multiple"}, :remote => :true do |f|
  =f.fields_for :hours do |hour|
    =hour.select :day, (0..6)
    =hour.select :start_time, [6,7,8] # some start times
    =hour.select :stop_time, [9,10,11] # some stop times
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know haml at all, but I'll try

You should work with it through `BuisnessController`. Here is form for `new` and `edit` action:

```
=form_for @buisness do |f|
  =f.fields_for :hours do |hour|
    =hour.select :day, (0..6)
    =hour.select :start_time, [6,7,8] # some start times
    =hour.select :stop_time, [9,10,11] # some stop times
```

Comment: But form_for @business creates a form pointing to the business controller whereas I want it to go to the hours controller.